# IP Camera not getting captured by OpenCV Python on cloud instance

Tags: python, opencv, flask, rtsp

I've integrated IP Camera using OpenCV into a flask app. It works perfectly on my local system, but when I tried to deploy it on a Linux instance on AWS or on Azure App Service, the capture call returns false. I tried to stream a recorded .mp4 file on the instance, it worked without problems. My local system is running Windows. Can someone please help me to figure out the problem here ?

I've tried re-deploying and re-installing all the packages, but still facing the same problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the actual code and how you're integrating the IP Camera into a flask app.   What do you mean by deploying it on a Linux instance?  How are you deploying it?